# git commits heatmap for a newly created project from an existing one

Tags: gitlab, heatmap

I pushed an existing git project to Gitlab and wanted to have an intuitive impression of git commits history through the Gitlab heatmap. Yet from the heatmap, I could only tell that I pushed to this repo that day and all the previous git commit history wouldn't reflect in the heatmap.

Is there a way to show my previous git commits in the heatmap? Or is the heatmap only to reflect the actions caused by `git push`?

Answer (score 1):

It might be:

- a refresh issue (GitLab might take time analyzing the full commit history of the newly pushed repository to update the heatmap)
- a branch issue (mostly commits from master might only be shown)
- a date issue (maybe some commits are too old to be show in the activity heatmap default time scale)

Comment: I will follow https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/62129 for any answer from GitLab itself.

Comment: Thanks, I have joined Gitlab for nearly a year, It is always so, the project maintained by me alone has developed within a year and all commits were pushed to master branch.